# Default value not working in select tag if the user doesn't select any options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

---

Hello, 
I'm trying to make a default value of language selection to be English whose value is 1. So if the user doesn't select language option, it should still be 1 so that I can run my algorithm. But when I test it that doesn't select any value, it doesn't make it default value.

And I decided to check the datatype of language option, it's a string type, but even if I make if(isNaN(languageOption)){ languageOption = "1";}, it's still not working. Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you for your help

```
<body>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)"><img src="image/MindScribe-cursive.png" id="cursive"></a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <img src="image/MindScribe-zebra.png" id="ImageEnterVariables" alt="Hello, I'm Stripes">
    <img src="image/MindScribe-zebra2.png" id="onlyShowZebraImage" alt="Hello, I'm Stripes" style=display:none>

    <select id="languageSelection" style=display:none>
        <option value="">Choose a language</option>
        <option value="1">English (American)</option>
        <option value="2">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
        <option value="3">Japanese</option>
    </select>
<script>
    var languageOption = parseInt($("#languageSelection").val() );
    $("#languageSelection").on("change", function(){

        if(isNaN(languageOption)){ languageOption = "1";}
        languageOption = $(this).val();

        console.log("langugeOption is " + languageOption);

        console.log("Language changed to: "+ $(this).find("option").eq( $(this)[0].selectedIndex ).text() + " (Index: "+languageOption+")" );

        console.log(typeof(languageOption));  // Outputs string

        endingArr = [];
        runThroughArr = [];
        randomArr = [];

        if(languageOption === "1"){
            console.log("English");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }
        else if (languageOption === "2"){
            console.log("Chinese");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList_chi.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }

    });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing these much stuff for making **English** default value? You can just add **selected** attribute to that option which you want to make default.

```
<select id="languageSelection" style=display:none>
        <option value="">Choose a language</option>
        <option value="1" selected>English (American)</option>
        <option value="2">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
        <option value="3">Japanese</option>
</select>
```

And in your script, you can apply below logic to set default option to 1 :

```
 languageOption = $(this).val();
 if(languageOption==""){
    languageOption="1";
 }
```

```js
$("#languageSelection").on("change", function(){

        var languageOption = $(this).val();
       if(languageOption.length==0){
          languageOption=1;
        }
        console.log("langugeOption is " + languageOption);

        console.log("Language changed to: "+ $(this).find("option").eq( $(this)[0].selectedIndex ).text() + " (Index: "+languageOption+")" );

        console.log(typeof(languageOption));  // Outputs string

        endingArr = [];
        runThroughArr = [];
        randomArr = [];

        if(languageOption === "1"){
            console.log("English");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }
        else if (languageOption === "2"){
            console.log("Chinese");
            for(i = 0; i < intro_playList_chi.length; i++){
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
                if(intro_playList_chi[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="languageSelection" >
        <option value="">Choose a language</option>
        <option value="1">English (American)</option>
        <option value="2">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
        <option value="3">Japanese</option>
    </select>
```

Above code works for me, it gives me 1 if **Choose a language** is selected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I still want the user to see what to do in the dropdown, so the first one would be "Choose a language". And I did try languageOption = $(this).val();
 if(languageOption===""){
    languageOption="1";
 }. It's still not working

Comment: Thanks. But it's still not working for me... I'm not sure why...Is there any other ways?

Comment: @Johnny88520 in the scenario you explained (i.e. on change of Language dropdown) it should work, Are you trying to get dropdown value somewhere else without changing the dropdown?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but what I'm trying to do is if the user doesn't select anything, which is if(isNaN(languageOption)){ languageOption = "1";} then goes into the for loop to append those arrpay, i.e. endingArr, runThroughArr, and randomArr.  But for some reason, I have to choose either English, Chinese, or Japanese in order to go to the for loop. I don't know what happens

Answer (score 0):

If you need the "Choose a language" to be displayed, set its value to 1 (the same as English):

```
<option value="1">Choose a language</option>
```

Comment: That's smart. But still not working for me. Thank you for replying. Is there any other ways?